# Using smtplib in a function will not read To:, From:, and subject line

Tags: python, email, smtplib

When I run my code outside of the function, everything displays correctly but when I add it in a function the subject, to and from lines don't appear in the email

```
def change_other():
message = """\

Subject: {Employee} -- Change -- Title Change
From: test@test.com
To: test@test.com


We have received a title update for {Employee}. 

    Title: {Title}

    Old: {Old}

    New: {New}

    Profit Center: {PC}

    Supervisor: {Supervisor}


"""

from_address = "test@test.com"
password = "abc123"

smtp = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.office365.com",587)
context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.office365.com",587) as server:
    server.starttls(context=context)
    server.login(from_address, password)

    for i, r in db[field2].iterrows():     
            server.sendmail(
                from_address,
                "test@test.com",
                message.format(Employee=r["Employee Name"],
                   Old=r["Old Value"],
                               New=r["New Value"],
                               PC=r["PC"],
                               Title=r["Title"],
                               Email=r["Email"], 
                               Supervisor=r["Supervisor Name"]


                )
            )
```

The point of this is to send different emails based on a certain input on a csv file.

I do get emails but they are just missing the subject, to and from in the email. The body shows up just fine.

Comment: The message starts with a newline, which is odd.  Try `message = """Subject: ...` instead.

Comment: If I do that, the to, from and subject shows up in the body. The subject line is still blank and so is the to line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this out by testing. In my actual code I had tabbed the TO,FROM and SUBJECT. Once I removed them and aligned them with the beginning of the function, it worked.